# CSS styleSheet asp.net Core 2.1

Tags: html, css, asp.net

After many research my css stylesheet wont link to my index page
Any idea ? [This my path folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVYMa.png)

this is my code :

```html
<link href="~/style/MainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server"/>
<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: stylesheets should be included in the head part. You might want to look up the default structure of an html file, for example [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html)

Comment: I did include my stylesheet in the head and it didn't work ..

Comment: Please go to your view source and navigate to that style url from there. You will get more idea, where the path points

Comment: Why dont you put your css files in wwwroot folder.